# What does the orange colored text in a SkyVector route indicate?

Tags: flight-planning, flight-simulator, fms

If you use a pre-made route in [skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/), sometimes there will be orange text.

For example: from KIAD to KTPA with default cruise settings, the second route in the list will have DADES6 in orange.

What does this mean and how would you program these into the FMC?

[image]

Comment: Green text is an airway, orange text is a SID/STAR.

Comment: Thank you J. Hougaard! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dades 6 is an arrival procedure also known as a STAR (Standard Terminal Arrival Route).

The plate that lists the route and altitudes/speeds for the arrival can be found [here](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1902/pdf/00416DADES.PDF).

If you are using a flight simulator, there should be an ARR/DEP page on the FMS that includes (among other things) a list of all the arrivals for the airport you have set as your destination. You can then select the arrival and the appropriate runways.